# Is `ifup -a --force` interrupting network connection?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am trying to add static route in Ubuntu 14 server
And I want to not interrupt network connection already established.

I see that with `route` I can add static route. But If I want to make that static route happen, I should add config to `/etc/networking/interfaces`.

Is there a way to not interrupting network connection 
  and applying changes in `/etc/networking/interfaces`?

Would `ifup -a --forfe` do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, using "route add" will directly modify the linux routing table. Adding it to /etc/networking/interfaces will make it persistent during reboot.

If you do "route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0", then check with " netstat -r" for the result.